# Can not print any output after the second for loop - match.group with regex

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

text = input()
total_calories = 0

pattern = re.compile(r'([#|])(\w+\s?\w+?)\1(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d)\1(\d{1,5})\1')
matches = pattern.finditer(text)

for match in matches:
    total_calories += int(match.group(4))
days_left = total_calories // 2000
print(f"You have food to last you for: {days_left} days!")
for match in matches:
    print(f"Item: {match.group(2)}, Best before: {match.group(3)}, Nutrition: {match.group(4)}")`enter code here`
```

Code is working properly down to the second **for loop**. Why I can't print any output after the second for loop? During debugging I see that the program just exit without error when is reaching the second **for loop**

Comment: `.finditer()` returns an *iterator* - after you've looped all the way through it once, in the first `for` loop, there are no items left.  Use `.findall()` instead, which returns a list that you can iterate over as many times as you want.

Comment: or use `list(...finditer(...))`

Answer (score 0):

As `re.finditer` returns an iterator, your first loop will consume all values and nothing will remain to be iterated by the second loop.

In this particular case you can merge the logic of both loops into one:

```
total_calories = 0
details = []
for match in matches:
    total_calories += int(match.group(4))
    details.append(f"Item: {match.group(2)}, Best before: {match.group(3)}, Nutrition: {match.group(4)}")

days_left = total_calories // 2000
print(f"You have food to last you for: {days_left} days!")
print("\n".join(details))
```